# Reposition yahoo media player?

Tags: css, media-player, yahoo

I'm making a website for a piano player, and I'm using the yahoo media player to play a short playlist of his music in the background while navigating the site. I've been looking for a way to reposition the player on the page, but I wasn't able to come up with any easy way of doing this. Does anyone know of a practical means of doing so?

Comment: Hi mopsys, welcome to Stackoverflow! You're more likely to get a better response from our community if you show your code. This demonstrates that you've actually put some effort into your problem, and it also gives the community a place to start when diving in to help you. Click the **edit** link below your question to edit it and add the missing code. Good luck!